# An error is reported when HUAWEI Drive Kit is used to query the file list

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I want to use the HUAWEI Drive service in my app. My app has integrated HUAWEI Drive Kit 4.0.3.300. When my app calls the Drive.Files.Create(File content) API to upload a file, the upload failed, and error code 403 is reported in the log.
I checked the HUAWEI ID sign-in code and found that the Drive scope is correctly set, and the Android Studio version is 3.6.3.
The error information in the log is as follows:

```
{"error":{"code":403,"description":"Not sign agreement, please confirm","errorDetail":[{"reason":"AGREEMENT_NOT_SIGNED","domain":"global","errorCode":"21004033","description":"Not sign agreement, please confirm"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error information indicates that you have not signed HUAWEI Drive Kit user agreement. Please visit https://cloud.huawei.com/ to sign this agreement.

Please refer to the following document for more error code information:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/drivekit-devreference

Comment: In case anybody stumbles upon this. This is the right answer and should be accepted. Important note: This refers to the end user, not the developer. The end user has not accepted Drive agreement. You could somehow refer them to the page to sign the agreement.